# Can't run a hello world program in Android Studio

Tags: android

I just installed the latest Android Studio to get started off with Android app development. I have 2 GB of RAM running in my 32-bit laptop. As soon as I try to run the basic hello world program, it gives me the following error message. I don't understand this. Do I have all the necessary packages installed or is there something missing? Please tell me I don't have to update any hardware.

```
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
emulator: device fd:592
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

Comment: are you using android studio or eclipse?

Comment: as it says, Try reducing yor emulator ram size to `800MB`, you dont have `1536MB` in you physical system

Comment: i am using android studio version 1.0.1

Comment: will reducing to 800 mb help? If so? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i think you have 3 options here

**Number 1**

Use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter)

**Number 2**

Start testing on a real android device

**Number 3 (i like this more)**

Edit the AVD that you are using and set the memory to 512 MB

> will reducing to 800 mb help? If so? How do I do that?

First step

```
Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager
```

Second Step

```
Select your device and click Edit button in right part of window
```

Third Step

```
In Memory Options secton find RAM parameter and set it to 512. Click OK for saving option
```

Rerun the emulator and it should work.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Click on `AVD manager`,it will open already created avd. Click on `edit AVD icon` which as right side (second last). after that click on `show advance setting`. from here you can reduce size of RAM to 512 MB. Good Luck